# How to use JUnit with eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, selenium-rc, selenium-webdriver

I want to use JUnit as test framework with Selenium using eclipse as IDE. I am using Java for Selenium. Which jar file needed to add as library?

Comment: Yes, I have got 4.11 and 4.10 (.jar) for using with eclipse. 1) junit-4.11-SNAPSHOT-20120416-1530.jar 2) junit-4.10.jar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Create a project.
2. Add jUnit jar in its build path.
3. Write a java class that extends TestCase.
4. Write a method that strats with "*test*" word like "*testXX()*" in the created class.
5. Run the class as jUnit.